# ASP.Net MVC Post: key-value pairs - can't retrieve value

Tags: asp.net-mvc, post, key-value

I have a forms collection (fc) and I'm attempting to append to an email the values of the 'key' and the 'value'.  I'm having no problem with the key (newKey), but I can't seem to code the 'value' properly.  The 'for' loop checks to see if the key's first 3 characters of the key are 'ddl' indicating it came from a dropdownlist.   if so, the loop should append the value from the dropdownlist control (the value of the key-value pair).  (If not, the loop calls another method to append either a yes or no based upon the value of a checkbox control) Thanks in advance.

```
       //Append new key-value pairs implemented since legacy keys
        for (int i = 0; i < newKeys.Length; i++ )
        {

            //Checks for prefix of element to determine type of element
            if(newKeys[i].Substring(0,3) == "ddl"){
                sb.Append(newKeys[i] + ":  " + fc.GetValue(newKeys[i]) + "\",<br />");
                sb.Append(newKeys[i] + ":  " + fc.GetValues(newKeys[i].ToString())  + "\",<br />");
            }
            else{
            sb.Append(newKeys[i] + ",\"" + Boolean(fc[newKeys[i]]) + "\",<br />");
            }
        }
```

The 2 sb.append commands return the following:

ddlStratacacheConstellationManagerRole: **System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult"**
ddlStratacacheConstellationManagerRole: **System.String[]",**

Comment: what is happening instead? Could you provide us with an example output (or input)?

Comment: The first sb.Append is returning the following value:  System.Web.Mvc.ValueProviderResult".      The seconding sb.Append is returning the following value: System.String[]"  BY THE WAY, I have omitted the key values in the above results since they come out just fine!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The values you are writing aren't of type `String`, nor they have the `ToString()` method overridden.

That's why the standard `object.ToString()` method is called and the object's type name is appended to the string.

To remedy this, you either need to override the `ToString()` method of all possible form collection's values, or think of some other algorithm, which would iterate over collections and output the corresponding values.